# What is a "real server" for websockets in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, websocket

The documentation for [Network.WebSockets.runServer](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.9.6.1/docs/Network-WebSockets.html#v:runServer) says:

> Note that this is merely provided for quick-and-dirty standalone applications, for real applications, you should use a real server.

Is this "real server" a reference to something that I'm supposed to know about (if I were more familiar with the Haskell ecosystem), or something that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Cross-posted this question to the [websockets](https://github.com/jaspervdj/websockets/issues/111) issue tracker.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual server can be any TCP application. All you need is support of Berkeley socket from your programming language. This is a nice tutorial from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) on how to write a websocket server.

The real production quality server in Haskell ecosystem is [warp](http://www.stackage.org/package/warp). You can use [wai-websockets](http://www.stackage.org/package/wai-websockets) to target it to Warp. In fact `wai-websockets` uses the package `websockets` internally.